# jquery ui, detect real droppable area on hover off nested droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to build a nesting `droppable` place, on `drop` events I'm appending custom HTML object that it's maybe a `droppable`(Here's always `droppable`),

now the question is:

1. **How can I call droppable again for new appended element via current option?**
2. **I want to detect real droppable area on over, Do I have it right or is there a better way?
   (as regards
   droppable are nested)**

**here is example**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6oxmmm5/)

Comment: Once you've appended the element, you can call droppable on it. If that is not what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better example of what I mentioned in the comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pd3pur85/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function makeDrop(target) {
    target.droppable({
      greedy: true,
      tolerance: 'touch',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.detach();
        var newDrop = $("<div>", {
          class: "drop"
        }).appendTo($(event.target));
        $('.drop').removeClass('drag-hover');
        makeDrop(newDrop);
      },
      over: function(event, ui) {
        $('.drop').removeClass('drag-hover');
        $(event.target).addClass('drag-hover');
      },
    });
  }

  makeDrop($(".drop"));

  $('.drag').draggable({
    revert: 'true',
    helper: "clone",
  });
});
```

You can then assign Droppable to your dynamically created `<div>` during `drop`.

As far as your `over`, I suspect this is the best use for this at this time.

Comment: Everything is ok, thx so much; but now we confront new challenge that's may be a bug: nesting droppable `over`event not triggered for ancestor of Internal droppable accepted drop **Perform the following steps:** (1) - Click on and drag "drag me" button onto the inner Droppable
(2) - Release and drop it 
(3) - Note that the border color of current droppable changes on `over` event
(4) - Now! click and drag button again to the previous droppable accepted drop (5) - see no change on border affected of ancestor

Comment: That's going to be a tough one. Consider how `over` is working. Can try to switch into `drag`, but you will need to collect all the `.drop` elements and check if the item being dragged is "over" or within the boundaries of the element. I wonder if `z-index` would help over determine the proper target.

Comment: This is good but i think the problem is don't triggering `out` for Internal droppable accepted drop at `drop` event in greedy `droppable` ,this is maybe a bug, not resolve via z-index. Anyway, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Tarcisiofl have you posted a question? Not sure what type of help you are looking for.